# Google app engine javascript not found

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I am using GAE Launcher to deploy my application (th3b706.appspot.com), but i have an strange issue when im working local everything works just fine but as soon as i deploy the *.js files arent there. I added

```
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: templates\scripts
```

to my app.yaml file.

and the scripts are in the scripts folder, just like i said local is everything alright as soon as i upload the js files get lost idk why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your separator and it should be ok:

```
static_dir: templates/scripts
```